# Android: How to save image from camera to a specific folder and view it in my device's gallery?

Tags: android

as described in the title I would like to save the image from camera in a specific folder and then view it in the gallery of my device. So far I can access the camera, take the photo and show it in an ImageView in the same layout. How could I do? I read on the net to use the provider but using it, the images taken with the camera are not displayed in the gallery of my device. Thanks in advance to those who will answer.

This is my code:

```
public class CamActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button photoButton;
    private Button saveToGallery;
    private String currentPhotoPath;
    private File photoFile = null;

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_camera);
        imageView =  findViewById(R.id.taken_photo);
        photoButton = findViewById(R.id.btnCaptureImage);
        saveToGallery = findViewById(R.id.gallery_save);

        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(checkPermissions()) {
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                    galleryAddPic();
                }
            }
        });

        saveToGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        } else  {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Toast.makeText(CamActivity.this, "error" + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.myapp.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        //Check permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Permission Granted
            return true;
        } else {
            //Permission not granted, ask for permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So how should I replace getExternalFilesDir ()?

Comment: I undid the deletion of the previous question and as I said earlier there are no exhaustive answers.

Comment: Well reread my last comment there. A full explanation why it did not work. You could have asked there which path to use instead.

Comment: Thank you, I have reread your answer several times, but I still don't understand how I should make that folder visible to the media store. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It should be clear that the path delivered by getExternalFilesDir is not suitable fot the media store. So the only thing you have to do is use a different path. I also said that ten minutes ago.

Comment: I also answered to this by asking you 10 minutes ago how to replace getExternalFilesDir()

Comment: Put them on external storage. There is a get function with that name too.

Comment: I've tried to use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() but then it gives error on fileprovider

Comment: And you are not telling us which error? You want us to guess and let this to take more amd more time?

Comment: Sorry but I've been trying to rewrite the code for several hours and I haven't really thought about it. However the error is: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20210117_201551_1134796645.jpg

Comment: Clearly you did not set up your FileProvider in the right way. That error has been reported on stackoverflow a hundred times and a bit if googling would have tolf you jow to solve it. And you also did not update the code in your post. In this way it takes time and time.

Comment: In reality I searched on google and the problem occurs on my device as the app crashes and freezes (which it doesn't do on the emulator) consequently I tried as said before to completely rewrite the code. Do you have other solutions to the problem?

Comment: Maybe you don't understand what I said. I have set the provider correctly in fact I am not shown any error in the console but on my device the app crashes